# What are the required steps to use Beeline to query a remote Hadoop instance?

Tags: macos, hadoop, terminal, hive, beeline

I have a Hadoop cluster running on another server. I am able to ssh into that server and use Hive to run queries. I'm trying to determine if I can query that server remotely, using Hive or Beeline; would prefer Beeline, since it's not being deprecated.

I used Homebrew to install Hadoop and Hive. However it complains about missing environment variables and path. But it seems like those things are set, so I must not have configured it correctly. So, what are the steps I need to go through to execute queries on a remote Hadoop from my Mac? Do I have to go through [all the steps](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GettingStartedWithHadoop) to set up a local Hadoop instance just so I can query a remote Hadoop?

```
~ (master) 10:24:30  
# next line is from the docs
$ beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default -n scott -w password_file
Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must be set or hadoop must be in the path

~ (master) 10:25:05  
$ which hadoop
/usr/local/bin/hadoop

~ (master) 10:25:18  
$ echo $HADOOP_HOME
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/bin
```

Comment: `localhost` isn't a remote node...?

Comment: I strongly suggest that you download a solid JDBC client for OSX *(on Windows I would go for DBVisualizer..)*, download the Cloudera JDBC driver which does not require the same mess of Hadoop deps as the Apache driver, and work happily.